# Fix TypeError when creating a bar chart and count plot using pandas, matplotlib, and seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, google-colaboratory

How to fix the TypeError in the following code using pandas, matplotlib, and seaborn libraries to create a bar chart and count plot for the 'Sex' and 'Survived' columns of the DataFrame df_train?

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('../content/train.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('../content/test.csv')
df_submission = pd.read_csv('../content/sample_submission.csv')

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(18, 8))

df_train[['Sex', 'Survived']].groupby(['Sex'], as_index=True).mean().plot.bar(ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('Survived vs Sex')

sns.countplot('Sex', hue='Survived', data=df_train, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('Sex: Survived vs Dead')

plt.show()
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-38b53be3f652> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 ax[0].set_title('Survived vs Sex')
      5 
----> 6 sns.countplot('Sex', hue='Survived', data=df_train, ax=ax[1])
      7 ax[1].set_title('Sex: Survived vs Dead')
      8 

TypeError: countplot() got multiple values for argument 'data'
```

I tried to fix the problem by finding similar questions and answers, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you try: `sns.countplot(x='Sex', hue='Survived', data=df_train, ax=ax[1])`
`ax[1].set_title('Sex: Survived vs Dead')`?

Comment: It works as you said! thx